# iOS - Xcode 8.0 issue with UITableViewCell for image loading while showing those images in live preview of xCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, xcode8

I was creating **UITableViewCell** for **remote image** it was **not showing** them on **device** as well as on **simulator** but if you debug it through **xCode live preview** its showing them there.
Before xCode 8.0 it's working fine.
I know there are iOS players who can catch this ball.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: same issue I am facing. Have you got any solution?

Comment: i investigate in details and find out that the tableview cell has update some of its frame check each item frame in which you are getting issue specialy first time rendering of tableview.